# Joining two tables to print selective data.

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables -

*TableA* metadata:

```
idA(PK)    descA     idB
```

*TableB* metadata:

```
idB(PK)    assetidC
```

*TableC* metadata:

```
assetidC(PK)   descC
```

It is a one to many relationship

The following select query -

```
select distinct A.idA, C.descC 
from tableA A, tableB B, tableC C
where C.descC like '%test%'
  and C.assetidC = B.assetidC
  and B.idB = A.idB
```

returns results like -

```
idA       descC
1         "I test Java"
1         "I test Oracle"
1         "I test Windows"
1         "I test Software"
2         "I test Java"
2         "I test Oracle"
2         "I test Windows"
3         "I test Java"
3         "I test Oracle"
4         "I test Windows"
4         "I test Software"
```

What I want is - distinct idAs *no matter which descC it picks!*

```
 idA       descC
    1         "I test Java"
    2         "I test Java"
    3         "I test Java"
    4         "I test Software"
```

What should I add to the query?

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can do this using a `group by` rather than `distinct`:

```
select A.idA, C.descC 
from tableA A, tableB B, tableC C
where C.descC like '%test%'
  and C.assetidC = B.assetidC
  and B.idB = A.idB
group by A.idA;
```

This happens to use a feature of MySQL called hidden columns, where columns in the `select` are not in the `group by`.  MySQL includes an arbitrary value for those columns.  This appears to be exactly what you want.  Normally, I find this feature more confusing than helpful.  Note that the column is *arbitrary* not *random*.  You might get the same value for all the columns.

Comment: `select A.parent_master_id, C.source_uri  from master_map A, asset B, asset_edition C 
where C.upload_uri like '%volume1/PHOTOS%' 
and C.asset_id=B.asset_id
and B.master_id=A.child_master_id`

This is the actual query returning some 700 results... when I add groupby... it returns more than 6000 results.

Comment: m sorry but the group by clause is grouping all the data from three tables... something is messing up.